# How I get data to flutter app from AWS RDS database

Tags: android, database, amazon-web-services, flutter, cloud

I need to get data from an AWS RDS database to my flutter up. I read that I need an endpoint to achieve this but I don't understand what this exactly means.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Amplify framework [here](https://docs.amplify.aws/start/q/integration/flutter/) or you can also check workaround from [this](https://hoonblizz.medium.com/flutter-aws-realtime-database-part-1-3ba1936046b4) link.